# How can I use EF Code First to declare a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to define a simple **one-to-many relationship between two poco's**, using the Entity Framework fluent API.

```
~ Team ~
public int TeamId { get; set; }
public ICollection<User> TeamMembers { get; set; } // All the team players. Two way nav.
public Player CreatedBy { get; set; } // Which player created this team. One way navigation.
                                      // Optional. Not all players create a team.

~ Player ~
public int PlayerId { get; set; }
public Team Team { get; set; } // The other side of the TeamMembers navigation.
```

NOTES:

- A player doesn't have to be in a team. (unassigned/dropped players).
- A team might have no players (they have all left/quit).

The closest I thought I got was something like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
        .HasOptional(x => x.TeamMembers)
        .WithMany()
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

This doesn't work, and I'm not sure how to define the other navs also.

Comment: You simply need to make your reference properties (instance and collection properties) virtual.

Comment: I thought that was for lazy loading. (which i definitely do not want) .. and proxy management?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this object model is what you are looking for:

```
public class Team
{    
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Player> TeamMembers { get; set; } 
    public Player CreatedBy { get; set; } 
}

public class Player
{
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; } 
}       

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
                    .HasOptional(p => p.Team)
                    .WithMany(t => t.TeamMembers)
                    .Map(c => c.MapKey("TeamId"));

        // Or alternatively you could start from the Team object:
        modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
                    .HasMany(t => t.TeamMembers)
                    .WithOptional(p => p.Team)
                    .Map(c => c.MapKey("TeamId"));
    }
}
```

BTW, the following fluent API code that you are using is not correct:

```
...HasOptional(x => x.TeamMembers)
```

Because TeamMembers is a collection and cannot be used by *HasOptional* method which always has to be invoked with a single object.

#### Update - HasRequired vs. HasOptional:

While they both set up an association, they deliver slightly different results and have different requirements:

- If it's a FK association (the FK property is exposed on the dependent object) then it must be a nullable type when using *HasOptional* and non-nullable type when using *HasRequired* or Code First will throw.
- Code First will automatically switch cascade deletes on when using *HasRequired* method.
- The other difference is the EF runtime behavior when it comes to deletion. Consider a scenario where we want to delete the principal object (e.g. `Team`) while it has a dependent object (e.g. `Player`) and cascade delete is switched off. With *HasOptional* EF runtime will silently update the dependent FK column to null while with *HasRequired* EF will throw and ask you to either explicitly remove the dependent object or relate it to another principal object (If you want to try this you should be aware that in both cases both principal and dependent objects must be already loaded in context so that EF will have a track of them).

Comment: @Morteza Manavi - is there any chance you could add to your answer :: a quick explanation of the differences/uses of HasOptional/HasMany/HasRequired with regards to table relationships, please?

Comment: @Morteza Manavi - thanks heaps for the update :) I still don't fully understand 1 thing :: `FK Property is exposed on the dependent object`. <= Does this mean it doesn't have to be an int? So `public Player CreatedBy` is the FK Property on the `Team` class that is NOT nullable (ie. a team cannot exist without a player created it). We do -not- need to have a `public int PlayerId` on the `Team` class? Is that correct?

Comment: Also, can you give an example of setting the Relationship if you went from the Team up to the player? Ie the class has 1-to-many other-classes.

Comment: No problem. No, what I meant by that is to distinguish EF 4.0 `FK associations` from EF 3.5 `independent associations`. `CreatedBy` is not a FK property, it's a navigation property, but if you add an `int` property like `PlayerId` to back `CreatedBy` then `PlayerId` would be the FK property and your association becomes a FK association (right now it's an independent association). Now, if you define `PlayerId` as `int?` then you would have a nullable FK in your object model ready to be configured by `HasOptional` fluent API method.

Comment: I've also updated the fluent API code in my answer to show how you can  go from the Team object up to the player.

Comment: @Morteza Manavi So what are these independent associations? I thought a `Team` property on my `Player` class says: `Player`s have a 0-1 relationship with a `Team` .. which means that the `Player DB` table will have a FK `TeamId` and therefore EF is smart enough to figure this out with our modelling?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: Yes, your understanding is correct, it's just a matter of defining that `TeamId` in your `Player` class. Take a look at this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/10/27/foreign-keys-in-the-conceptual-and-object-models.aspx

Comment: @Morteza Manavi - Whenever I try to add the `modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()` association AND i add both the parent nav `public Team Team {...}` to `class Player` .. and the child nav `public ICollection<Player> TeamMembers { .. }` to `class Team` .. AND try to add a new player with no Team .. my sql statement is always saying this `INSERT INTO [dbo].[Players] (Team_TeamId) Values (NULL) ..` .. notice the field name `Team_TeamId` ? That's wrong :( And I can't seem to fix this. It should be `INSERT INTO ... (TeamId) VALUES(null)` ... ???

Comment: That's the default FK column name that Code First have chosen, you can change this by fluent API or simply by adding a TeamId as int to the Player class.

Comment: @Morteza Manavi ahhhh!!! and how can I use the fluent api to define that? I currently have ` modelBuilder.Entity<Team>().HasKey(x => x.TeamId);` but it still is giving me `Team_TeamId` .. ??

Comment: You should use the `Map` method. I've update the fluent API code in my answer to show you how.

Comment: @Morteza Manavi cheers mate for all the help :) much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to get this to work automatically simply by doing something like this:

```
 public class Team {
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
}
```

But you'll have to be more specifical about what exactly you mean when you say "doesn't work". What doesn't work, exactly? Are you getting an error message? If so, what is it? Is the Team property of the Player object always returning null?